# stack smashing error

Tags: mysql, c, stdin, fgets, stdio

This is my code:

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *server = "nope";
    char *user = "nope";
    char *password = "nope";
    char *database = "nope";
    unsigned int port = 0;

int cprint(char *text){//Imprime como encabezado el numero de productos sin stock sumado al argumento
    MYSQL *conn;
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    my_ulonglong num;

    conn = mysql_init(NULL);

    /* Connect to database */
    if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
    user, password, database, port, NULL, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }

    /* send SQL query */
    if (mysql_query(conn, "SELECT id FROM productos WHERE stock <= 0")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }

    res = mysql_store_result(conn);
    num = mysql_num_rows(res);

    printf("\n===============================\n\n");
    if(num > 0){
        printf("Productos sin stock: %llu\n",num);
    }
    else{
        printf("No hay productos sin stock\n");
    }
    printf("\n===============================\n\n%s",text);   

    /*close connection */
    mysql_free_result(res);
    mysql_close(conn);

return 0;
}

char *remove_newline(char *s)
{
    int len = strlen(s);

    if (len > 0 && s[len-1] == '\n')  // if there's a newline
        s[len-1] = '\0';          // truncate the string

    return s;
}

int newproduct(){
    char *name = malloc(127*sizeof(char));//nombre del producto
    char *desc = malloc(127*sizeof(char));//descripcion del producto
    double price;//precio del producto
    cprint("Agregar nuevo producto\n\n");
    printf("Nombre del producto: ");
    fgets(name, 127, stdin);
    name = remove_newline(name);
    printf("Descripcion: ");
    fgets(desc, 127, stdin);
    name = remove_newline(desc);
    printf("Precio: ");
    scanf("%e", &price);

    MYSQL *conn;
    conn = mysql_init(NULL);
    printf("Mysql initiated\n");
    if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
    user, password, database, port, NULL, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("connection established\n");
    char rname[256];//string donde guardar el nombre con caracteres de escape
    char rdesc[256];
    printf("Vars declared\n");
    mysql_real_escape_string(conn,rname,name,256);//se agregan los caracteres de escape
    printf("name escaped\n");
    mysql_real_escape_string(conn,rdesc,desc,256);
    printf("desc escaped\n");
    /*
    char *query;//donde guardar el query

    snprintf(query,1000,"INSERT INTO productos (nombre,descripcion,stock,precio) VALUES( %s,%s, 0, %e)",rname,rdesc,price);//query a enviar

    if (mysql_query(conn, query)) {//enviar el query
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }*/

    mysql_close(conn);
    printf("Mysql closed\n");
return 0;
}


int main(){
    printf("Sales Assistant Alpha v0.0\n");//Nombre y version del programa
    unsigned int choice;//numero de eleccion del menu
    char *err = NULL;//Error
    while(1){//loop infinito
        cprint("Menu Principal\n\n");//imprime el encabezado
        printf("1-Agregar nuevo producto\n");
        printf("2-Editar producto existente\n");
        printf("3-Productos sin stock\n");
        printf("4-Agregar pedido\n");
        printf("5-Salir de la aplicacion\n\n");

        if(err != NULL){//evalua si hubo un error y lo imprime
            printf("%s\n",err);
            err = NULL;
        }



        printf("Numero de eleccion: ");
        scanf("%i",&choice);//pide eleccion
        if (scanf("%*[^\n]") != EOF){//read and discard all non-newlines
        scanf("%*c"); //then read and discard the newline
        }
        switch(choice){//evalua la eleccion y ejecuta la funcion correspondiente
            case 1:
                newproduct();
                printf("returned\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                exit(0);//termina el programa
                break;
            default:
                err = "Eleccion no valida";//error
                break;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

And the console execution:

```
Sales Assistant Alpha v0.0

===============================

Productos sin stock: 3

===============================

Menu Principal

1-Agregar nuevo producto
2-Editar producto existente
3-Productos sin stock
4-Agregar pedido
5-Salir de la aplicacion

Numero de eleccion: 1

===============================

Productos sin stock: 3

===============================

Agregar nuevo producto

Nombre del producto: a
Descripcion: a
Precio: 1
Mysql initiated
connection established
Vars declared
name escaped
desc escaped
Mysql closed
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./sales_assistant terminated
Aborted (core dumped)


------------------
(program exited with code: 134)
Press return to continue
```

i have this stack smashing thing that is unknown to me. Besides that i want to know how much memory i can safely allocate without getting bus error.

IMPORTANT:when i disable the mysql_real_escape_string functions the code works normally, so the problem is there, but i dont know what the problem is.

thanks, matt.

***edited***
Added the complete code and translated to english. Also changed the question because i got a new error. Added debugging code.

Comment: What happens in the run up to the call to newproduct()?  A common reason for fgets "not working" is a preceding call to scanf leaving a '/n' in the input stream.

Comment: What happens before you call `newproduct`? Looks like `stdin` is borked. And can we see the code for `remove_newline`?

Comment: I looked up the '/n' thing and i solved it!, thank you very much Nigel!

Answer (score 2):

When you ask for a number with `scanf("%i", &choice);` (the result of which should be checked!), you leave the newline behind.  When you read a line with `fgets()` in `newproduct()`, it reads the newline left behind.

Ultimately, if you're doing line-based inputs, use `fgets()` or `readline()` (from POSIX 2008) to read the line and `sscanf()` to parse the line.

Comment: thanks for answering. but i changed the question because i got another error and i didnt want to make a whole new question for the same code.

Comment: It makes life difficult, doesn't it...You've got the code for `remove_newline()` in your program twice!  Is `Precio` in the trace `Price` in the code?  Where does your debugger say the crash occurs?  You're mainly using MySQL library code from after the input of `Price`, so the chances are you're miscalling something.  Add debugging prints between the various function calls so you know what's failing (if you can't do it in the debugger).  Make a minimal test case (see [Simple, Self-Contained, Complete Example](http://sscce.org/) for guidance on how and why).

Comment: the code is in spanish, i translated it here but i did it badly as i see. sorry for that. the remove_newline repetition is also a copy-paste error, its only once in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

your malloc() is wrong for a (char*)

should be:

```
char *name = malloc(127*sizeof(char));//nombre del producto
char *desc = malloc(127*sizeof(char));
```

Comment: sizeof(char) is always 1 so this "correction" doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed mysql_real_escape_string(). the thing was that the length argument must be the *from lenght instead of the *to lenght like i was doing. im very happy that i worked that thing out, i was getting really frustrated.